# Replace last matched substring of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to replace a matched last substring of string

Example

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX)= 'Greeting<br><br>As many offices move to remote work. <br><br>Have a good day<br><br>'

SELECT REPLACE(@string,'<br><br>','')
```

Result need

```
 @string = 'Greeting<br><br>As many offices move to remote work. <br><br>Have a good day'
```

Need to replace the last two 
 with empty

Comment: And how do you define "last substring of string"?

Comment: I tried with replace but all <br> wil be replaced

Comment: @DaleKi have edited question please check once, I need to rpelace last one of string but my code replacing all <br>

Comment: If its always the last 8 chars just use substring.

Answer (score 0):

If the performance is not an issue, you can try reversing the string and then cut the first section and reverse it back

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX)= 'Greeting<br><br>As many offices move to remote work. <br><br>Have a good day<br><br>'

declare @pat nvarchar(max) = (select REVERSE('<br><br>'))
declare @rsv nvarchar(max) = (select REVERSE(@string))
declare @idx int = (select CHARINDEX(@pat, @rsv, 0))

declare @result nvarchar(max) = (select left(@rsv, @idx - 1) + right(@rsv, len(@rsv) - @idx - LEN(@pat) + 1))
set @result = reverse(@result)

print @result
```

**Result is:**

```
Greeting<br><br>As many offices move to remote work. <br><br>Have a good day
```

You can shorten the code. I just made it verbose so the logic will be clear.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always on the end another simpler method would be to add a special character to the string then replace including that.

```
select @string=Replace(@string+'~','<br><br>~','')
```